# ¿Cómo agregar varios check constraint en "alter table"?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Les dejo mi intento de query:

```
ALTER TABLE telefono_contacto ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_Parentesco_contacto CHECK 
(parentesco_contacto = "AMIGO" AND parentesco_contacto = "VECINO" AND parentesco_contacto = 
"TITULAR" AND parentesco_contacto = "FAMILIAR");
```

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de generar este query aplicando los 4 checks?

Comment: Estrictamente no es query, sino una sentencia DDL. Sepáralos con una coma: `ADD CONSTRAINT ... , ADD CONSTRAINT ... , ADD CONSTRAINT ...;`. Pero suena a que lo puedes hacer con `parentesco_contacto IN('AMIGO', 'VECINO', 'TITULAR', 'FAMILIAR')` a reserva de que expliques mejor lo que requieres.

Comment: No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta en caso que te haya servido... @Minor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera correcta y más legible sería la siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE telefono_contacto ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_Parentesco_contacto CHECK (parentesco_contacto in('AMIGO', 'VECINO','TITULAR','FAMILIAR'));
```

Saludos.